# A list of wireless connections doesn't appear in Asus k501ux

Tags: wireless, drivers, kubuntu

Please help with wireless (may be drivers or other settings). I have asus k501ux and I have already installed kubuntu 15.10 on it, butit doesn't see any wi-fi network.

[No any networks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVn6g.png)

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280 shows folowing:

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)


    bogdan@asus-bogdan:~$ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    2.858927] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    2.905389] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.921112] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.30.14.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.952391] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[    2.952465] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.952912] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.979027] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[    3.015432] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 453 at /build/linux-HVWSXI/linux-4.2.0/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:1447 iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x2a2/0x2b0 [iwlwifi]()
[    3.015434] Modules linked in: snd_hda_codec_hdmi i2c_designware_platform(+) iwlmvm(+) snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic i2c_designware_core mac80211 asus_nb_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap mxm_wmi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_hda_intel kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul iwlwifi snd_pcm aesni_intel cfg80211 aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul snd_seq_midi glue_helper snd_seq_midi_event ablk_helper cryptd snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer input_leds serio_raw snd uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops soundcore videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media idma64 btusb virt_dma btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth shpchp mei_me mei intel_lpss_pci processor_thermal_device intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal wmi intel_lpss_acpi
[    3.015475] CPU: 1 PID: 453 Comm: irq/130-iwlwifi Tainted: G        W       4.2.0-35-generic #40-Ubuntu
[    3.015497]  [<ffffffffc0664482>] iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x2a2/0x2b0 [iwlwifi]
[    3.015500]  [<ffffffffc06530ea>] iwl_read_direct32+0x3a/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[    3.015503]  [<ffffffffc06531e3>] iwl_poll_direct_bit+0x43/0x70 [iwlwifi]
[    3.015507]  [<ffffffffc065a174>] iwl_pcie_rx_stop+0x34/0x40 [iwlwifi]
[    3.015510]  [<ffffffffc0664ad7>] iwl_trans_pcie_stop_device+0x5f7/0x630 [iwlwifi]
[    3.015514]  [<ffffffffc06644ce>] iwl_trans_pcie_rf_kill+0x3e/0x50 [iwlwifi]
[    3.015517]  [<ffffffffc065b1c7>] iwl_pcie_irq_handler+0xba7/0x1500 [iwlwifi]
[    3.427243] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   17.016173] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[   66.682577] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.

bogdan@asus-bogdan:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: '3:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5110]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi'

Comment: Please also add output of `dmesg | grep iwlwifi`

Comment: I've added this info

Comment: It is OK with the drivers and firmware. It is blocked by `rfkill`. Please add output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: Is it `X501UX` or `K501UX`. It should be added if it is "K".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wireless adapter is blocked by `rfkill`.

It is an Asus UEFI issue.

This can be fixed by

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf <<< "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4"
```

Reboot after this command and test.

This solution should help. A quirk for this Asus laptop [has been added](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/platform/x86/asus-nb-wmi.c?id=d2044c5a3aafac552d28c1add16930821c24cbd0) to upstream kernels. It is actually the same fix as this `options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4`.

Comment: It helped!!! And wi-fi is now connected. Thanks for you help! Where did you learn, that it should work?

Comment: I added a link to the upstream commit.

Comment: excuse me, I have seen your answers for asus touchpad drivers. Do you know, can I install drivers to enable multitouch, scrolling and zooming?
Now I have this warning: https://yadi.sk/i/lCKpt3SXqpmtA

Comment: You'd better ask a new question regarding the touchpad and post output of `xinput` there.